# Installing XpsDrv sample under the Windows XP

Tags: xps

this [article](http://kibitzercz.blogspot.cz/2012/01/building-and-using-xpsdrvsmpl-under.html) helped me to install "XpsDrv sample" under the Windows XP. But I'd like to ask if it's possible to automate step No. 6

> As you go on, the wizard can ask you for some files it cannot find. But this should be no big trouble if you have SP3 or XPS Extension Pack installed. 
>   If the wizard asks you for xdsmpl.gpd, click Browse and find this file in `[sample root]\install\x86`.
>   If it asks for xdwmark.dll, navigate to `[sample root]\install\x86` as well.
>   For msxpsinc.gpd go to `c:\windows\Driver cache\i386`.
>   The xpssvcs.dll file should be found in `c:\windows\system32`.

I need to install XPS driver during the installation process of my App and it's not acceptable for my customer to find missing files manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is copy the **x86** folder and rename it to **i386**. Then find missing files **(msxpsinc.gpd**, **xpssvcs.dll**) and copy them to the `[sample root]\install`